# Create general exception class when implement retry in Python

Tags: python, exception

As the title explains, I want to create a general exception class to inherit from built-in exception classes that would be caught later in other class(es).

Here is my code:

```
from functools import wraps


class ControlledException(TypeError, AttributeError):
    """A generic exception on the program's domain."""


class WithRetry:
    def __init__(self, retries_limit=3, allowed_exceptions=None):
        self.retries_limit = retries_limit
        self.allowed_exceptions = allowed_exceptions or (ControlledException,)

    def __call__(self, operation):
        @wraps(operation)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            last_raised = None

            for _ in range(self.retries_limit):
                try:
                    return operation(*args, **kwargs)
                except self.allowed_exceptions as e:
                    print(f'retrying {operation.__qualname__} due to {e}')
                    last_raised = e
            raise last_raised

        return wrapped


@WithRetry()
def test(x):
    x = x + 1
    print(x)


test('a')
```

`ControlledException` class inherits two exceptions, `TypeError` and `AttributeError` which I want to catch. In this case, the program will catch the `TypeError`.

And I have no idea why the parameter `self.allowed_exceptions` has no effect on (ControlledException,)...
However, if I change (ControlledException,) to Exception or TypeError the error is caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define custom exceptions like that, either you have to `raise` them directly or you have to catch the original exceptions and then raise the custom exceptions.

Here, I've caught the original exception, suppressed their traceback and raised your custom exception.

```py
from functools import wraps


class ControlledException(TypeError, AttributeError):
    """A generic exception on the program's domain."""


class WithRetry:
    def __init__(self, retries_limit=3, allowed_exceptions=None):
        self.retries_limit = retries_limit
        self.allowed_exceptions = allowed_exceptions or (ControlledException,)

    def __call__(self, operation):
        @wraps(operation)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):

            for _ in range(self.retries_limit):
                try:
                    return operation(*args, **kwargs)

                # if you want to catch the error, you have to catch the original
                # exceptions as opposed to custom exceptions
                except (TypeError, AttributeError) as exc:
                    print(f"retrying {operation.__qualname__} due to {exc}")

                    # this suppresses the original error message and raises your
                    # custom exception
                    raise ControlledException("Here is your error message!!") from None

        return wrapped


@WithRetry()
def test(x):
    x = x + 1
    print(x)


test("a")
```

This prints out:

```py
retrying test due to can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ControlledException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-364-2a7d6eb73e92> in <module>
     38 
     39 
---> 40 test('a')

<ipython-input-364-2a7d6eb73e92> in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     27                     # this suppresses the original error message and raises your
     28                     # custom exception
---> 29                     raise ControlledException('Here is your error message!!') from None
     30 
     31         return wrapped

ControlledException: Here is your error message!!
```